# Bent raster after Build Overviews for mosaic dataset using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, mosaic-dataset

I created a mosaic dataset from a set of 12 tiff's spanning the united states.  Before running `Build Overviews`, the images all join together nicely.  But after, they look like this:

[image]

Any idea what is going on?  Did i do something wrong?  Should I have merged the mosaic to a single image first?

Per the comment by @PolyGeo, here is a detailed step by step:

1. Gather source data from the [FAA](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/ifr/) (The 12 files under *High Altitude Enroute (U.S.) GEO-TIFF Files*)

   1. Unzip each zip file into a directory
   2. Each of these `tif` files have an associated `html` file that shows some metadata, specifically:

> ```
> Geodetic_Model:
>     Horizontal_Datum_Name: North American Datum of 1983
>     Ellipsoid_Name: Geodetic Reference System 80
>     Semi-major_Axis: 6378137.000000
>     Denominator_of_Flattening_Ratio: 298.257222
> ```

2. Open ArcMap (10.3.1.4959 License type Advanced), then create a new *Blank Map*
3. Under catalog, right click on any gdb, choose *New -> Mosaic Dataset...*
4. On the *Create Mosaic Dataset* dialog:

   1. Under *Coordinate System*, choose NAD 1983
   2. Click *Environments...*
   3. Under *Raster Storage* set *Pyramid resampling technique* and *Resample* to *CUBIC*
   4. Click *OK*
5. Once the dataset is created, right click it and *Add Rasters...*

   1. Under *Input Data* choose *Dataset* then browse for the 12 tif files from 1.1 above
   2. Set *Environments...* the same as 4.2 above
   3. Click *OK*
6. Then, I created feature polygons for each tif by clicking through the map file at all the corners of the useful data and used that to [modify the footprints for each raster](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/import-mosaic-dataset-geometry.htm) (note that I also set *Always Clip The Image To Its Footprint*)

At this point I have a nicely stitched together mosaic dataset.  But when i zoom out past `1:1,250,000` it stopped rendering the image.  I analyzed the dataset which provided the warning that I was missing overviews.  So i went ahead and right clicked the mosaic dataset, then *Optimize -> Build Overviews*.  The result, is what you see in the attached image...

Comment: I'll bet it is related to your coordinate systems.  I think you should [edit] your question to include more precise details of your workflow, paying particular attention to the coordinate systems of your data, data frame, and anywhere a tool used gave you the option to choose one.

Comment: @PolyGeo, you were right...  The source data was using a custom coordinate system that was _slightly_ different from the coordinate system i chose.  So i reimported the images with their natural coordinate system, saved it as a favorite, then redid the whole process always setting to the custom coordinate system.  If you wanna make your comment an answer, ill mark it off.  And thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet it is related to your coordinate systems. I think you should review your workflow, paying particular attention to the coordinate systems of your data, data frame, and anywhere a tool used gave you the option to choose one.

Your comment confirmed my expectation:

> you were right... The source data was using a custom coordinate system
>   that was slightly different from the coordinate system i chose. So i
>   reimported the images with their natural coordinate system, saved it
>   as a favorite, then redid the whole process always setting to the
>   custom coordinate system.